# Copy files from subfolder to folder using SSH

Tags: ssh, copy

How do I copy all files inside `/directory/subfolder` to `/directory` using SSH?

PS. I'm not going from 1 server to another, I'm just trying copy the files in the subfolder to update the site...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with SSH though I have used [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to do what you asked using an SSH connection. It was fairly easy, though I didn't have to deal with the server-side settings.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Does it keep any permissions that were set or will I need to set them again?

Comment: I believe there is a section in the actual application to save the profile. So I guess you could have it keep the permission if you make a profile.

Answer (score 15):

```
scp -r /directory/subfolder/* user@host:/directory
```

Comment: For those who don't know, -r switch means recursively.

Answer (score 4):

```
cp -a <from-path> <to-path>
```

might end up looking like

```
cp -a /var/www/site.com/dir/ /var/www/newsite.com/dir/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scp -r user1@from-server:/dir1 user2@to-server:/dir2

scp -r local-directory  user2@to-server:/dir

scp -r user1@from-server:/dir local-directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `sftp` and specifically the `put` command.  [Here is some documentation on `sftp`](http://kb.iu.edu/data/akqg.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your needs and your underlying OS. If you are on a box with X/windows and are trying copy files, you can use FileZilla, WinSCP and load the files via sftp. Another nice method is to use ExpanDrive, MacFusion, [WebDrive](http://www.southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/winindex.html) or [WebDrive for MAC](http://www.southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/mac/index.html)  and simply mount an external directory as a local drive. If you are only interested in a console solution, you maybe want to take a look at "scp".

Answer (score 0):

```
PULL:
# ssh target_address cat remotefile > localfile
# ssh target_address dd if=remotefile | dd of=localfile
# ssh target_address cat "<" remotefile >localfile
# ssh target_address cat "<" remotefile.gz | gunzip >localfile
```